# I made an edit but didn't realise I was not logged in

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

I made an edit to a post but didn't realise I was not logged in until after I submitted the change. Is there any way to assign it to me?

This happened only a few moments ago, the edit number is [823878](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/823878) for the post answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1006553/10857

I thought when it said that I could "sign up" to assign it to me, that I could click it, use my existing Google account and it would just work - but it didn't. Instead it just signed me in and showed me the review page (which is why I know the edit number is: `823878`).

Please help.

Comment: The edit has been rejected, so you can suggest it again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the best possible outcome for you is to hope for the anonymous edit suggestion to get rejected so that you can suggest from your account once more (I have rejected it).

That said, in my honest opinion, this edit suggestion is completely superfluous, and it doesn't help improving the readability of the post. I myself would reject similar edit suggestions in future too.

**Update:** On a second thought, I won't reject the edit-suggestion (if you make another) as it does fix some grammatical issues.

Comment: Yes, changing "I don't" to "I do not" is not helpful. "I don't" is absolutely fine and perfectly gramatical. Some of the other changes suggested were useful though.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have made another amend - this time making sure I was logged in first. I took everyone's comments on board and made it better.

Answer (score 6):

Nope, sorry. At least, this isn't something that moderators can do and I would expect it would only be possible if an SE employee were to manually edit the database. That's really a lot of work for something very minor and I really doubt they'd be willing to do it.